# Vite: This module can only be imported inside a service worker

Tags: npm, sass, vite, sveltekit, terser

After a `pnpm` package update, I can't start my SvelteKit project anymore. Something is messy with the tooling: `pnpm`, `vite`, `sass`, `terser` or `sveltekit`, I don't know.

```bash
> pnpm run dev
VITE v4.0.0  ready in 2880 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
...

This module can only be imported inside a service worker
    at $service-worker:3:8
    at instantiateModule (file:///Users/me/myapp/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.0.0_sass@1.56.2+terser@5.16.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ed9cb113.js:53246:15)
```

This point out to this line (I have no clue what it does):

```js
try {
   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
   const AsyncFunction = async function () { }.constructor;
   const initModule = new AsyncFunction(`global`, ssrModuleExportsKey, ssrImportMetaKey, ssrImportKey, ssrDynamicImportKey, ssrExportAllKey, '"use strict";' + result.code + `\n//# sourceURL=${mod.url}`);
   await initModule(context.global, ssrModule, ssrImportMeta, ssrImport, ssrDynamicImport, ssrExportAll);  <---------- HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason (auto import in VsCode I guess), the following import was added in my code inside a `+page.svelte` file: `import { prerendered } from "$service-worker";`.

Never used that but this was the source of evil. I which I could get the incriminated line and file in the VsCode terminal, or in the Chrome console ... If someone knows how this could happens, I'll take it